# JSON data conversion (Array to Object)

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data in the format of

```
{
  tag: 'new-tag',
  stream_subjects: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

and I need to convert it into like this:

```
{
  tag: 'new-tag',
  stream_subjects: [
    {subject_id: 1},
    {subject_id: 2},
    {subject_id: 3}
  ]
}
```

I have to use `Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => { }` for this. Plz help. How can I do this?

```
Object.keys(params.data).forEach((k) => {
  console.log(`${k} - ${params.data[k]}`);
  if (typeof params.data[k] === 'object') {
    temp[k] = {};
    for (const innerKey in params.data[k]) {
      temp[k].subject_id = params.data[k];
    }
  } else {
    temp[k] = params.data[k];
  }
  console.log(temp);
});
```

Comment: Read the documentation of `Object.keys`, attempt something and come back.

Comment: Object.keys(params.data).forEach((k) => {
    console.log(`${k} - ${params.data[k]}`);
    if (typeof params.data[k] === 'object') {
      temp[k] = {};
      for (const innerKey in params.data[k]) {
        temp[k].subject_id = params.data[k];
      }
    } else {
      temp[k] = params.data[k];
    }
    console.log(temp);
  });

this is my code now can you tell what I am doing wrong

Comment: @AmitKumar , did the solution work for you ?  

const temp={};
Object.keys(params).forEach((k) => {
  console.log(`${k} - ${params[k]}`);

  if (Array.isArray(params[k])) {
    temp[k]=[];
    params[k].forEach(key => temp[k].push({'subject_id': key}));

  } else {
    temp[k] = params[k];
  }
  console.log(temp);
});

Answer (score 0):

I did some modification to your code. Please check it out below.

```
const temp={};
Object.keys(params).forEach((k) => {
  console.log(`${k} - ${params[k]}`);

  if (Array.isArray(params[k])) {
    temp[k]=[];
    params[k].forEach(key => temp[k].push({'subject_id': key}));

  } else {
    temp[k] = params[k];
  }
  console.log(temp);
});
```

Comment: Not 100% but I got the idea of what I was doing wrong. Thanx for the help!

Comment: Ok you are welcome, could you please post the solution once you are done, so that I am also aware what I was doing wrong . Thank you !